# Someone or some websites always make wrong prediction

Tags: word-choice

Is there a simple way or words to describe someone or some websites always make wrong prediction to the future outcome?

Like if he/it says some tennis player is going to win, then we think that player is probably going to lose.

Comment: So rather than *unreliable*, they're *reliably incorrect*?

Comment: @snailplane Yeah, and I want to choose your comment as answer!

Answer (score 1):

I admit. I could not find a *single term* for this. **One of the phrases** that I would use here is **not** *wrong prediction* but...

> *bad [predictor](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/predictor)* - *Ah, don't believe him, he is a bad predictor **or** ...don't believe that website, it's a bad predictor.*

Answer (score 1):

You might try this term:

> A false prognosticator.

Answer (score 1):

> His/Her/Their predictions are always wrong.

or

> His/Her/Their predictions always turn out wrong.

which is usually a symptom of people

> not knowing what they are talking about.

All of these expression are quite common.  Of course the last one doesn't have a lot to do with predictions, but it's related.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use this eg. "they generally get wrong with their predictions/assumptions..you should be more cautios about their predictions.